# MATLAB .NET assembly (Undefined function or variable 'feedforwardnet')

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, matlab, com-interface

I'm trying to integrate [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) 2010b with Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

I have the following MATLAB method.

```
function varargout = perform( func, varargin )

%% // Set default values
workspaceDirectory = ['Results/MatlabWorkspace_' datestr(now, 'yyyy-mm-dd_HH-MM-SS')];

clear args
args = struct('workspacePath', [ workspaceDirectory '/workspace.mat'], ...
              'testArray', [], ...
              'k', 50, ...
              'rate', 0.0001, ...
              'trainingDataPath', 'P2AT_LaserImageVectorList.csv', ...
              'network', 'feedforwardnet', ...
              'initialWeights', [], ...
              'divideFcn', 'dividerand', ...
              'trainRatio', 70/100, ...
              'testRatio', 15/100, ...
              'valRatio', 15/100, ...
              'trainInd', [], ...
              'testInd', [], ...
              'valInd', [], ...
              'trainFcn', 'trainlm', ...
              'performFcn', 'mse', ...
              'biasConnect', [0; 0; 0], ...
              'layerSize', [9; 4; 1], ...
              'layerTransferFcn', ['tansig '; 'tansig '; 'purelin'], ...
              'max_fail', 10, ...
              'mu_dec', 0.04, ...
              'useInitialWeights', false, ...
              'saveResults', true);

% // Returns a modified properties structure
args = getopt(args,varargin);

args.layerTransferFcn = cellstr(args.layerTransferFcn);

if args.saveResults && ~strcmpi(func,'test')
    if (exist(workspaceDirectory, 'dir') ~= 7)
        mkdir(workspaceDirectory);
    end
end

if (strcmpi(func,'test'))
    try
        load(args.workspacePath, '-regexp', '.*');
    catch err
        Warning(err.message);
        varargin{1,1} = null;
        return;
    end

    data_inputAngle = args.testArray(2501);
    data_inputPCA = args.testArray(1:2500);

    if size(data_inputPCA,1) == 1
        data_inputPCA = data_inputPCA';
    end

    switch(featureExtractionMethod)
        case {'gha','apex'}
            % // [W, errvals] = gha(data_inputPCA, k, varargin{1,3});
            data_PCs  = W' * data_inputPCA;
            data_inputNN = [data_PCs; data_inputAngle];

        case 'nnmf'
            % // [W,H,D] = nnmf(data_inputPCA',k);
            data_PCs  = H * data_inputPCA;
            data_inputNN = [data_PCs; data_inputAngle];

        case 'pcaProcess'

        otherwise
            warning = 'ERROR: no feature extraction method has been defined.';
            Warning('ERROR: no feature extraction method has been defined.');
            varargout{1,1} = null;
            return;
    end

    % // Just to test to see if it recognizes 'feedforwardnet'.
    testnet = feedforwardnet;    % // <------------------------------- LINE 81

    % // Saving all the workspace variables to see if they are all correctly processed.
    save('all');

    varargout{1,1} = net(data_inputNN); %// <------------------------- LINE 86

    end
end
```

And this is how I create my DLL file to import in Visual Studio:

```
%%// Determine path names
workdir = pwd();
outdir = fullfile(workdir, 'Output');
dnetdir = fullfile(workdir, 'dotnet');

%%// Determine file names
mfile = fullfile(workdir, 'perform.m');
dnetdll = fullfile(dnetdir, 'dotnet.dll');

%%// Build .NET Assembly
eval(['mcc -N -d ''' dnetdir ''' -W ''dotnet:dotnet,' ...
        'dotnetclass,0.0,private'' -T link:lib ''' mfile '''']);
```

So everything works perfectly fine when I use [MATLAB Engine's](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-engine.html) [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) interface to run the routine inside MATLAB from C#:

```
/*
 * This function calls the routine inside
 * MATLAB using the MATLAB Engine's COM interface
 */
static private float MatlabTestDebug(float[] testData, Double targetAngle)
    {
        Array X = new double[testData.Length + 1];
        testData.CopyTo(X, 0);
        X.SetValue((double)targetAngle, testData.Length);

        Array zerosX = new double[X.GetLength(0)];

        MLApp.MLAppClass matlab = new MLApp.MLAppClass();

        matlab.PutFullMatrix("testArray", "base", X, zerosX);
        matlab.PutWorkspaceData("workspacePath", "base", "workspace.mat");

        // Using Engine Interface, execute the ML command
        // contained in quotes.
        matlab.Execute("cd 'c:\\Users\\H\\Documents\\Project\\Source Code\\MatlabFiles';");
        matlab.Execute("open perform.m");
        matlab.Execute("dbstop in perform.m");
        matlab.Execute("result = perform('test', 'workspacePath', 'workspace.mat', 'testArray', testArray);");
        matlab.Execute("com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.closeAll");

        return (double)matlab.GetVariable("result", "base");
    }
```

But when I use the .NET assembly, it's not recognizing 'feedforwardnet'. I used to get an error on line 86 (`net(data_inputNN)`). So I added a line to test to see if it at least recognizes 'feedforwardnet', but it didn't.

Note: I'm loading some variables from a file including "net" which is a neural network (`load(args.workspacePath, '-regexp', '.*');`)

Also in the MATLAB method if I load a saved "network" from file and then save it to see how it processes the network, it will save it as a "struct" instead of a "network".

I'm assuming it's loading it as a struct to begin with.

I also had this problem inside MATLAB 2009b itself. That's the reason I'm using MATLAB 2010b now, because apparently MATLAB 2009b didn't have this particular neural networks toolbox.

Following is the C# code to use the .NET assembly.

```
/*
 * Calls the method from inside a .NET assembly created with MATLAB
 * using Builder for .NET.
 */
private float MatlabTest(float[] testData, Double targetAngle)
    {
        if (testData != null)
        {
            dotnetclass AClass = new dotnetclass();

            Array X = new double[testData.Length + 1];
            testData.CopyTo(X, 0);
            X.SetValue((double)targetAngle, testData.Length);

            MWNumericArray XNumericArray = new MWNumericArray(X);

            MWArray[] RetVal = AClass.perform(1, "test",
                "workspacePath", "workspace.mat",
                "testArray", XNumericArray);

            Array result = ((MWNumericArray)RetVal[0]).ToVector(MWArrayComponent.Real);

            return (float)result.GetValue(0);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0f;
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error in Visual Studio:

```
... MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error ...
Undefined function or variable 'feedforwardnet'.
Error in => perform.m at line 81.
```

---

NOTE: version of my compiler and softwares:

Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0`

MATLAB: R2010b (64-bit)

Visual Studio: MVS 2008 professional (.NET Framework 3.5 SP1)

Microsoft Windows SDK 6.1

---

**Recent Updates:**

I've added the path of the neural network toolbox in [mcc](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/compiler/mcc.html).

```
eval(['mcc -N -p ''C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\nnet'' -d ''' dnetdir ''' -W ''dotnet:dotnet,' ...
    'dotnetclass,0.0,private'' -T link:lib -v ''' mfile '''']);
```

Now I get these messages in `mccExcludeFiles.log`:

> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\@network\network.m
>
> > called by C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnnetwork\cascadeforwardnet.m
> >     (because of toolbox compilability rules)
>
> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\@network\network.m
>
> > called by C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnnetwork\feedforwardnet.m
> >     (because of toolbox compilability rules)

Answer (score 1):

The only answer I could come up with (which not a solution to the problem) was from *[Creating standalone application that contains neural network toolbox functions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/247626)*, stating that:

> You will not be able to compile any
>   function which trains the network 
>   (like ADAPT). Though the link does not
>   explicitly list these funcions (like
>   ADAPT), they fall under the 'All other
>   command line functionality'.
>
> However, you can deploy a M function
>   code which uses a pre-trained 
>   network. I believe the SIM function
>   will deploy fine.
>
> The workflow I see is:
>
> 1. In MATLAB, train you network using test input/output
> 2. Save the network (MAT file?)
> 3. Create a deployable function which then uses the pretrained network for 
>      new data. The network itself would not
>      change/adapt/train in this function
> 4. Compile and deploy the above function